# Rounded Rectangle shape to image retrieving from server in android

Tags: android

I want to give rounded rectangle shape to the images that I am fetching them from the server and displaying in list view. 
Currently I am able to make the images in a rounded rectangle shape which are available in my drawable folder. But finding the difficulties for the images fetching from the server.

Please let me know how can I do this..

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Round corners to view, simply create xml for drawable, apply Radius rate to your image corner as well as you can apply background color to your view too, check below code and steps.

Create one folder named *Drawable* within Res, keep below xml in drawable and you can set at runtime or in layout xml to your view.

> round_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#5a5a5a"/>
<corners android:radius="10px"/>
<padding android:left="20dp" android:top="20dp" android:right="20dp" android:bottom="20dp"/> 
</shape>
```

> Within xml

```
 android:background="@drawable/round_border"
```

> Jave code

```
ImageView im=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    im.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_border);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int radius=5;
int margin=5;

Picasso.with(context)
    .load(imageurl)
    .transform(new RoundedCornersTransformation(radius,margin))
    .into(imageview);
```

RoundedCornersTransformation.java

```
public class RoundedCornersTransformation implements Transformation {

    public enum CornerType {
        ALL,
        TOP_LEFT, TOP_RIGHT, BOTTOM_LEFT, BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        TOP, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT,
        OTHER_TOP_LEFT, OTHER_TOP_RIGHT, OTHER_BOTTOM_LEFT, OTHER_BOTTOM_RIGHT,
        DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_LEFT, DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_RIGHT
    }

    private int mRadius;
    private int mDiameter;
    private int mMargin;
    private CornerType mCornerType;

    public RoundedCornersTransformation(int radius, int margin) {
        this(radius, margin, CornerType.ALL);
    }

    public RoundedCornersTransformation(int radius, int margin, CornerType cornerType) {
        mRadius = radius;
        mDiameter = radius * 2;
        mMargin = margin;
        mCornerType = cornerType;
    }

    @Override public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {

        int width = source.getWidth();
        int height = source.getHeight();

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setShader(new BitmapShader(source, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
        drawRoundRect(canvas, paint, width, height);
        source.recycle();

        return bitmap;
    }

    private void drawRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float width, float height) {
        float right = width - mMargin;
        float bottom = height - mMargin;

        switch (mCornerType) {
            case ALL:
                canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
                break;
            case TOP_LEFT:
                drawTopLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case TOP_RIGHT:
                drawTopRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case BOTTOM_LEFT:
                drawBottomLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case BOTTOM_RIGHT:
                drawBottomRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case TOP:
                drawTopRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case BOTTOM:
                drawBottomRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case LEFT:
                drawLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                drawRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case OTHER_TOP_LEFT:
                drawOtherTopLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case OTHER_TOP_RIGHT:
                drawOtherTopRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case OTHER_BOTTOM_LEFT:
                drawOtherBottomLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case OTHER_BOTTOM_RIGHT:
                drawOtherBottomRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_LEFT:
                drawDiagonalFromTopLeftRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            case DIAGONAL_FROM_TOP_RIGHT:
                drawDiagonalFromTopRightRoundRect(canvas, paint, right, bottom);
                break;
            default:
                canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius, paint);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void drawTopLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, mMargin + mDiameter),
                mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin + mRadius, mMargin + mRadius, bottom), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawTopRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius,
                mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(right - mRadius, mMargin + mRadius, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawBottomLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom),
                mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom - mRadius), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawBottomRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius,
                mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(right - mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawTopRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin + mRadius, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawBottomRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawOtherTopLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawOtherTopRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin, right, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawOtherBottomLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right, float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin + mRadius, right - mRadius, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawOtherBottomRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right,
                                               float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom), mRadius, mRadius,
                paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin + mRadius, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    private void drawDiagonalFromTopLeftRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right,
                                                  float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, mMargin + mDiameter, mMargin + mDiameter),
                mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, bottom - mDiameter, right, bottom), mRadius,
                mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin + mRadius, right - mDiameter, bottom), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mDiameter, mMargin, right, bottom - mRadius), paint);
    }

    private void drawDiagonalFromTopRightRoundRect(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float right,
                                                   float bottom) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(right - mDiameter, mMargin, right, mMargin + mDiameter), mRadius,
                mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(mMargin, bottom - mDiameter, mMargin + mDiameter, bottom),
                mRadius, mRadius, paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin, mMargin, right - mRadius, bottom - mRadius), paint);
        canvas.drawRect(new RectF(mMargin + mRadius, mMargin + mRadius, right, bottom), paint);
    }

    @Override public String key() {
        return "RoundedTransformation(radius=" + mRadius + ", margin=" + mMargin + ", diameter="
                + mDiameter + ", cornerType=" + mCornerType.name() + ")";
    }
}
```