# android unable to round the corners of imageview?

Tags: android

I am making an application in which I want to round my ImageView by its corners. But it's not getting rounded from its corner, I have used the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="#6BC1F8" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
    android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

for rounding the corners of image..,but I am getting like this image :
[image]

and I want to do like below:

[image]

I am not sure where I am doing wrong, please guide me :)

Comment: you need round your image too, for now you just make round your imageView but your image is rectangle, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705239/how-should-i-give-images-rounded-corners-in-android for solving problem

Comment: probably duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners

Comment: [use this](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView)

Comment: Did u check [this???](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10151710/2591002)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Shape](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) in android to make the rounder corners

create the xml file named it as `roundcorner.xml` in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="#33DDFF" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape>
```

In your ImageButton add this attribute `android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"`

and use `android:src` to set the image for the imagebutton

**OR**

Use image view set `android:src = "your image"` , `android:background= "your shape "`and `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: How background can make rounded corners for image

Comment: I'm using an xml file as background and that xml file specifies that the corners should be rounded..@thealeksandr

Comment: Background will be rounded. But what about image?

Comment: In `android:src` attribute, specify the image that you want... @thealeksandr

Comment: Yes but you rounded background will be under the image. And It won't be rounded

Comment: Yes it will be rounded..It worked for me...Try it yourself...@thealeksandr

Comment: Sad that it didnt work for you..Any how it worked for me..@thealeksandr

Comment: See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032301/imagebutton-full-image-round-corners) @R.T.

Comment: @Lal can you give me your mailid??

Comment: @Lal do you leave in trivendum..,i nee dsome info..can you help me??

Comment: just because it is only working for round..not for sure..that time when i use dthis..i took circular ..but for rectngle not working.:(

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty nice way to create rounded `ImageView` programmatically.You can give it a try,

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;

public class ImageHelper {
    public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
                .getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = pixels;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
}
```

Also you can refer the sample app created by Romain Guy, a Google engineer

https://docs.google.com/a/impressol.com/file/d/0B3dxhm5xm1sia2NfM3VKTXNjUnc/edit?pli=1

references,

http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/11/android-recipe-1-image-with-rounded-corners/

[How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-to-have-rounded-corners)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#cccccc"
        android:startColor="#cccccc" />

    <corners android:radius="9dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#000000" />


</shape>
```

Using this as `android:background="@drawable/custom` for your imageview, you will get the following output.

[image: Screenshot of output]

**EDIT** : Increase the value of `android:radius` if you want more rounded corner. And if you don't want black border then remove the `<stroke ..... />`

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can't just add property as I know. You can do that only for shape. But you can do something like that:
Add two Imageviews. First image with transparent field inside with rounded corners. And second your image put under first image.